Using '&' inside CSS selector to find immediate children of an element using querySelector() or querySelectorAll()
If we have this HTML,
<ol class="parent-list">
  <li class="item">item 1</li>
  <li class="item">item 2</li>
  <li class="item">item 3</li>
  <li>
    <ol class="sub-list">
      <li class="item">item 1</li>
      <li class="item">item 2</li>
      <li class="item">item 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

Is it ok to use '&' inside querySelector() or querySelectorAll() to get immediate children of an element like this
const parentList = document.querySelector('ol.parent-list');
const immediateChildren = parentList.querySelectorAll('&>li.item');

The above code is working properly and if we try to remove '&' to get the immediate children list, it gives an error.
const parentList = document.querySelector('ol.parent-list');
const immediateChildren = parentList.querySelectorAll('>li.item'); // returns error

Is there any other recommended way for this or is this ok to use?

'&' has no place in a CSS selector, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors See also :scope on MDN as mentioned in the suggested duplicate.

That HTML is invalid. The subol should be inside an li.

@Harald I don’t understand “& has no place…”. It is now used in CSS nesting and I believe that the OP’s first method is valid (and makes more sense to me than :scope).

It can be used in a CSS file, yes, but I fail to find it as a selector, but maybe I am not looking in the right place. On https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors it appears under 'related concepts' only.
.... Oh wait, found it now: "If not used in nested style rule, the & nesting selector represents the scoping root." is on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector .
